# iOS Exception of adding NSNotificationCenter to a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I added a `NSNotificationCenter` to a `UIView`, when I first go to the page, the `NSNotificationCenter` work fine.
However, when I left that page and back to that page again, it will give out error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextMagnifierTimeWeightedPoint updateProfile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

Here are the code.

UIView1 :

```
- (void)changeUIView {
    UIView2 *view = [[UIView2 alloc] init];
    // show UIView2
}
```

UIView2 :

```
- (id)init {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProfile:) name:@"updateProfile" object:nil];
    return self;
}

-(void)updateProfile:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // do something
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:@"updateProfile"];
}

- (void)buttonClick {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateProfile" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Comment: where you are doing initialization of superview??

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `self` as the observer not the `selector` you are using to handle the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Or if you want to be specific you can use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"updateProfile" object:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it with you comment.

Comment: If this the right answer, could you accept so that others will know

Answer (score 1):

Always

***Add*** `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidAppear`

And

***Remove*** `NSNotificationCenter` in `viewDidDisAppear`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Let me try First.

Comment: These functions are available in UIViewController life cycle and not UIView.

Comment: Oh... yes, I am using UIView instead of UIViewController.